# I have to print last name from a three-name string,e.g.- ABV PQR SCW into SCW ABV PQR. But following code is not executing as desired

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Chan{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        int a,i;
        char c;
        String st="";
        int d=0;
        String s1="";
        String s2="";
        a=s.length();
        for(i=0;i<a;i++){
            c=s.charAt(i);
            if(c==' '){
                d=d+1;
            }
            if(d==2){/d is 2 at the space at third name
                s1=s.substring(i,a);
                st=s.substring(0,i);
            }
        }
        s2=s1+" "+st;
        System.out.println(s2);
    }
}
```

This code executes only by adding last character of last name before the entire name.What is wrong in the code?

Comment: It's time to introduce yourself to a **Debugger**

Comment: Used it,no help

Answer (score 0):

try splitting on a space

```
String input = "ABC DEF GHI";
String arr [] = input.split (" ");
System.out.println (arr[2] + " " + arr[0] + " " + arr[1]);
```

**note** better to use StringBuilder to *rebuild* your String

Comment: Sorry about that - fixed

Comment: Sorry from my side too. I get the split() one. I just want to figure out the error in my code that i've written in my question